# Showing $f$ is an $L^p$ function if $f$ is "self-convoluted.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

If $f$ is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f=f*f$, show that $f$ is $L^p$ for $2\leq p\leq \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Young's inequality says

$$
\|f\|_p = \|f*f\|_p \leq \|f\|_2\|f\|_q
$$

provided $1\leq p,q \leq \infty$ and

$$
\frac1q + \frac12 = \frac1p + 1
$$

If you let $q = 2$, $p = \infty$, you get $f \in L^\infty$ and you're done.

Comment: So $f\in L^2\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ implies that $f\in L^p$ for all $p$ inbetween?

Comment: Yes. Loosely speaking, being in $L^2$ ensures it decays well at $\infty$ (relative to $L^q$ with $q > p$) but could still allow unbounded behavior near some finite $x_0$. Being in $L^\infty$ prevents this, so it'll be in all the in between spaces. To prove this, note $|f|^q = |f|^2|f|^{q-2} \leq |f|^2 \|f\|^{q-2}_\infty$ provided $q \geq 2$.

Comment: The general statement (for endpoints other than $2$ and $\infty$) you'll find as "Littlewood's inequality" or maybe (as a corollary of) "Generalized Holder's inequality"